# Server side sorting does not occur

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Server sorting does not work for me. I use ORM Sequelize. By default, I have to sort by name and ascending. But when I want to do the sorting in descending order on the client, nothing happens, but such a request is displayed in the terminal.

> Executing (default): SELECT count(*) AS "count" FROM
> "spr_turbodrills" AS "spr_turbodrills";
>
> Executing (default):
> SELECT "turbodrill_id", "name", "spindle", "turbodrill_n",
> "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "spr_turbodrills" AS "spr_turbodrills"
> ORDER BY "spr_turbodrills"."name"
> **ASC** LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;

That is, the sorting based on the sql query did not occur at all.

Although if you look here then everything seems fine.

> GET /api/directory/spr_turbodrills/all?**order=desc**&pageSize=1&page=1 200
> 7.805 ms - 163

controller:

```
module.exports.getAllPaginate = async function (req, res) {
    try {
        const query = {
            offset:  +req.query.pageSize * ( +req.query.page - 1),
            limit:  +req.query.pageSize,
            order: [
                ['name', 'ASC']
            ]
        }
    
        const spr_turbodrills = await SprTurbodrills.findAndCountAll(query)
        res.status(200).json(spr_turbodrills)
    } catch(e) {
        errorHandler(res, e)
    }   
}
```

Comment: In you `controller` you dont handle the order parameter. You use explicit orderby `['name', 'ASC']`

Comment: I feel like you commented without even thinking of what I pointed out in my comment. Even @feiiiiii went and added a answer based on what I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its because you hard coded to always use `ASC` in your controller

```
module.exports.getAllPaginate = async function (req, res) {
try {
    const query = {
        offset:  +req.query.pageSize * ( +req.query.page - 1),
        limit:  +req.query.pageSize,
        order: [
            ['name', req.query.order]
        ]
    }

        const spr_turbodrills = await SprTurbodrills.findAndCountAll(query)
        res.status(200).json(spr_turbodrills)
    } catch(e) {
        errorHandler(res, e)
    }   
}
```

and then try with this:

`GET /api/directory/spr_turbodrills/all?order=DESC&pageSize=1&page=1`